# OpenMP | VS CODE | Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, openmp

How to enable OpenMP in Visual Studio Code?

I know we need to add a flag '-fopenmp', but I don't know where?

If possible share a keyboard shortcut to access the file.

Thanks!

Comment: VSCode is NOT an IDE. You need to have a compiler toolchain independent of VSCode. On Windows, if you are using MSBuild.exe, and CL.exe, you need to include this in the .vcxproj file. If you are on Linux, you need to specify this in the Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tryer solution of using Makefile is definitely useful and preferable.

---

Alternatively, one can pass it with g++ as:

```
g++ test.cc -o test -fopenmp
```